# Is there a non-iterating control that allows data-binding syntax to be used?

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, controls

Let's say I have a single XML node of content in my code-behind.  I need to get some data out of the various nodes and onto a Web form.

Traditionally, I would create a bunch of Literals on the page, then do stuff like this in the code-behind:

```
MyLiteral.Text = myXmlNode.SelectSingleNode("/some/xpath").InnerText;
```

This is fine and good, but consider the binding syntax we use in Repeaters:

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <p>
        <%# XPath("/some/xpath") %>
    </p>
</ItemTemplate>
```

So, I got to wondering if you can use this same syntax for non-Repeater situations.  It just seems odd that there wouldn't be the same syntax available for a non-iterating situation.

(Of course, if you didn't mind being ridiculous, you could bind your XML node to a Repeater, where it would only have one iteration. I *swear* I've never done this...)

I can't help but thinking that the designers of the framework would have planned for this.  Is there some non-iterating control I don't know about that allows you to bind a datasource and render using data binding expressions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have already discovered that [databinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228214.aspx) syntax only works with composite controls, such as repeaters, listviews, detailsView, etc.

Comment: Sad.  There should be a "BindableRegion" control or something.

Answer (score 0):

The best suggestion I can think of, is using something like the DetailsView or FormView. This will at least get rid of the issue of having "non repeating" data.